# Is it possible to set blur for a rect element in konva.js?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I want to use blur for rect elements (like filter: blur in css) in my React application. I tried to use it following konva tutorials but it doesn't work. It's possible? What am i doing wrong? This is my attempt at implementing this in my React application [code sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-cherry-7c1lp?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. To make it work, you need to make a bigger cache with `offset` attribute (https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#cache):

```js
ref.current.cache({ offset: 110 });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-rect-cache-p3pxl

Konva is calculating size of the cached canvas automatically. By default, for a rectangle shape, it will create a canvas with exactly the same size. Such cache will have only red pixels. So blur effect is not visible. Making cache bigger will add transparent pixels around the rectangle.

Comment: but with big blur it looks very strange. Not like HTML blur.
https://imgur.com/a/ejWo8wl

Comment: For some reason my comment was deleted. Once again, thank you for your answer :)